# After compiling a python script to EXE the Archive method doesn't work

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a python script that I compiled to an EXE, one of the purposes of it is to extract a 7z file and save it to a destination.
If I'm running it from PyCharm everything works great, this is the code:

```
    def delete_old_version_rename_new(self):
        winutils.delete(self.old_version)
        print("Extracting...")
        Archive(f"{self.new_version}_0.7z").extractall(f"{self.destination}")
        print("Finished")
        os.rename(self.new_version, self.new_name)
```

I used pyinstaller to compile the program and used to command `pyinstaller --onefile --paths {path to site packages} main.py`

Thanks!

Comment: Can't tell from here, but my guess is you've got the file path wrong,  if you're not explicitly setting a full file path, e.g. the 'current working directory' will be different between pycharm and your exe. Start with printing `self.destination`

Comment: self.destination is r"C:\devtree"

Answer (score 1):

Single-file executables self-extract to a temporary folder and run from there, so any relative paths will be relative to that folder *not* the location of executable you originally ran.

My solution is a code snippet such as this:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    app_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    app_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

which gives you the location of the executable in the single-file executable case or the location of the script in the case of running from source.

See the PyInstaller documentation [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html).

Comment: If i understand you correctly, if I will use --onedir instead of --onefile it should work fine?

Comment: This should work in all cases, I'm just more familiar with the `--onefile` approach and that's what you're using so that's the one I mentioned.

Comment: Though I am working on the assumption that it's not working because of path related issues. You weren't entirely clear in the question what was actually going wrong. You should definitely give more detail than "doesn't work".

Comment: I can't really tell what's going wrong as pyunpack doesn't give any status on the extraction process, seems like this line of code is not executing and I can't tell why. It started after compiling it to an EXE

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i just used a 7z command line i took from https://superuser.com/questions/95902/7-zip-and-unzipping-from-command-line
and used os.system() to initialize it.
Since my program is command line based it worked even better since its providing a status on the extraction process.
Only downside is i have to move the 7z.exe to the directory of my program.